# VStack with ForEach item rows but single selection of Toggle buttons

Tags: swiftui

I have a View with a VStack and ForEach and a @State Bool in SwiftUI.

```
struct mainView {

@State var selected: Bool


public var body: some View {
        
                        VStack(spacing: 0) {
                          
                                ForEach(viewModel.countryCodeResults, id:\.self) { 
                                    countryCodeResult in
                                    ResultRow(result: countryCodeResult, selected: $selected)  
                                }
    }

}

}
```

I pass the the selected bool as a Binding to the ResultRow() View.

Each one row Inside the ResultRow() consists of a Text() and toggle.

I need to give the ability to the user to select only one toggle and not multiple.

So each time a user taps a toggle it should be enabled only the toggle in that specific row and all toggles in other rows should be disabled. How is this possible using @State or @Binding

```
public struct ResultRow {

@Binding var selected: Bool

     public var body: some View {
    
                    HStack (spacing:10) {
      
                        Text("Toggle text")
    
                        Spacer()
    
                        Toggle("", isOn: $selected)
                               .toggleStyle(.radioButton)
                               .frame(maxWidth: 30)
                               
                        }
    
                    }
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selected.toggle()
   }
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The data model for contrycodeResults must have a boolean variable "selected" with the BOOL type, Now you can call countryCodeResult.selected.toggle() for each row

Comment: @AdR I do not quite understand could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.  Have `selected` track the country that is selected.  `""` represents no country is selected.  Each result row takes a country name and the `selected` binding, and it assigns its `country` to `selected` when it is selected.  Each row will style itself based upon the current setting of `selected`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let countries = ["Australia", "Brazil", "Canada", "China", "France", "Egypt", "India"]
    @State private var selected = ""
    
    public var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            
            ForEach(countries, id:\.self) { country in
                ResultRow(country: country, selected: $selected)
            }
        }
    }
    
}

public struct ResultRow: View {
    
    let country: String
    @Binding var selected: String
    @State private var isOn = false
    
    public var body: some View {
        
        HStack (spacing:10) {
            Text(country)
            Spacer()
            Toggle("", isOn: $isOn)
                .toggleStyle(.button)
                .frame(maxWidth: 30)
        }
        
        .lineLimit(1)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .onChange(of: selected) { _ in
            isOn = (country == selected)
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            isOn.toggle()
            selected = isOn ? country : ""
        }
        .onAppear {
            isOn = (country == selected)
        }
        
    }
}
```

---

**Note**: If one item *must* be selected at all times, then change `.onTapGesture { }` to:

```
.onTapGesture {
    isOn = true
    selected = country
}
```

and set the initial value of `selected` to one of the choices.